# Cursor disappears when using drawing tablet on Win8

Tags: windows-8, graphics-tablet

When I use my Aiptek drawing tablet with Windows 8, the mouse cursor disappears when I'm moving the stylus as a mouse (but not touching the surface). I can't find an option to turn it off and it worked fine on Win7. Is there anything I can do?